# Every time I need to use a command to mount an external hard disk in WSL

Tags: command-line, mount, hard-drive, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am using Ubuntu 18.10 in WSL in Windows 10. Whenever I open a Linux terminal with an external hard disk I need to use a command to mount the hard drive in the terminal. If I do not use the `sudo` command to mount the hard drive I cannot enter the hard drive directory.
Is there any solution for this. Please help me with this.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Please read [ask]. We need more details. Please [edit] your question to add the exact commands you run and their output, especially the error message you're receiving. You can copy-paste the text into the question and use [code formatting](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#code) to make it look nice.

Comment: You might find something helpful here [Automount additonal filesystems from fstab](https://github.com/Microsoft/WSL/issues/2636)